# Insert statment only insert one field into new table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a issue with an insert statement. It should transfer a row of data from one table to another upon clicking a link from a table from that specified row.

At the minute the only field being inserted into the other table is the reference.

In other words I want to retrieve a person's name and details from a row in one table which corresponds to a unique reference number and move it to the next table in the process.

Table Page.php

```
<td align="center"><a href="refertotriage.php?Reference=<? echo $rows['Reference']; ?>">Refer for Triage</a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="update.php?Reference=<? echo $rows['Reference']; ?>">Refer for IA</a></td>
```

Script.php - action page

```
require_once('auth.php');

 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
 $username="root"; // Mysql username
 $password="sysadmin"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="Elite"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="Instruction"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 $Reference=$_REQUEST['Reference'];
 $Forename=$_REQUEST['Forename'];
 $surname=$_REQUEST['surname'];
 $DOB=$_REQUEST['DOB'];
 $Mobile=$_REQUEST['Mobile'];
 $Home=$_REQUEST['Home'];
 $Address=$_REQUEST['Address'];
 $Postcode=$_REQUEST['Postcode1'];
 $Email=$_REQUEST['Email'];
 $Accident=$_REQUEST['Accident'];
 $Details=$_REQUEST['Details'];


 //semi colon removed  


  $sql="INSERT INTO 
 Triage 
 (
   Reference, 
   Forename,
   surname,
   `D.O.B`,
   `Mobile Number`,
   `Home Number`,
   Address,
   Postcode1,
   Email,
   Accident,
   Details
  )
 VALUES
   (
'".$Reference."',
'".$Forename."',
'".$surname."',
'".$DOB."',
'".$Mobile."',
'".$Home."',
'".$Address."',
'".$Postcode1."',
'".$Email."',
'".$Accident."',
'".$Details."'
  )";

  $result=mysql_query($sql);



 // echo "Successful";
 // echo "<BR>";
 // echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
 // mysql_error()

  echo $sql

  ?>
```

Comment: what does the sql query look like ? might be related to the content of $Reference

Comment: Be carefull, Sql Injection...

Comment: What happens when you echo $sql? Also, please do read up on SQL Injection - it looks like you're dealing with personal data, and your code is very vulnerable to attack.

Comment: Well if you attempt to insert the name `O'Henry` you can see how the query would break. You could escape your input values, but you should instead create parameterized queries in mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You are only passing the reference in your link ->`href="refertotriage.php?Reference=<? echo $rows['Reference']; ?>"`. Where do you expect to get the rest of your `$_REQUEST` parameters from? Since you are not submitting a form all the others will be empty.

Comment: once I have everything working I will look at sql injection as a few people have suggested some helpful ways of preventing it.

Comment: Again, what does `echo $sql;` print on page? You forgot the `;` btw

Comment: @Sean how would I change this to insert data from table 1 and move it into table 2?... I think your right in what your saying. im just pretty new to this

Comment: I think @Sean is on to something. If your other values are blank it's because they're not passeed. Either pass them with the reference, or use the reference to do a SELECT.

Comment: You can either change your link to a form for each row OR use the reference to query the data from the other table. The form would be if you are changing any of the data before inserting. The query would be if you are just copying the data to insert.

Comment: could anybody provide a example and I will give that a try. It should only be to move data from one table to the other and nothing should change